# Query to replace special characters in phone number field

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help with a query on how to replace special/non-numeric/hidden characters from a phone number column.

I've tried

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(
          PHONE_NBR,
          '[^[:digit:]][:cntrl:][:alpha:][:graph:][:blank:][:print:][:punct:][:space:]~',
          '')))
```

but no luck, there are still a few records which contain non-numeric values.

Comment: Formatting helps get answers when your question contains long expressions.  You also should show some examples of values which were processed correctly, and some examples of values which were not.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is saying to ONLY replace a string consisting of: a non-numeric character followed by a control character, an alpha, a graph, a blank, a print, a punct, a space, and then a tilde.

You should be able to just use `'[^[:digit:]]'` as your regex, to remove all non-numeric characters.

Comment: Yes, but there are few characters like 940374e+15,ar Drive R which are no getting replaced

Comment: @Keerthi that's a data type problem - seems like you're storing the phone as a number, or at some point it got converted to a number. It should be handled as a string, which will avoid scientific notation conversions.

Comment: @Keerthi, but 940374e+15 is not a phone number.

Comment: @Jasmine the phone number field is of string data type and it converted to decimal numbers. I just used '[^1234567890],'' and corrected the issue for now

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit True. So I'd have to change it to 94037415

Comment: Well no - 940374e+15 IS a number. Specifically, it's 940374000000000000000 - a very large number.